# kubectl get componentstatus shows unhealthy

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

i've finished setting up my HA k8s cluster using kubeadm.
Everything seems to be working fine, but after checking with the command **kubectl get componentstatus** I get:

```
NAME                 STATUS      MESSAGE
scheduler            Unhealthy   Get http://127.0.0.1:10251/healthz: dial tcp 12
controller-manager   Unhealthy   Get http://127.0.0.1:10252/healthz: dial tcp 12
etcd-0               Healthy     {"health":"true"}
etcd-2               Healthy     {"health":"true"}
etcd-1               Healthy     {"health":"true"}
```

I see that manifests for scheduler and controller have other ports set up for the health check:

**kube-scheduler.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    component: kube-scheduler
    tier: control-plane
  name: kube-scheduler
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  containers:
  - command:
    - kube-scheduler
    - --authentication-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/scheduler.conf
    - --authorization-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/scheduler.conf
    - --bind-address=127.0.0.1
    - --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/scheduler.conf
    - --leader-elect=true
    - --port=0
    image: k8s.gcr.io/kube-scheduler:v1.18.6
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    livenessProbe:
      failureThreshold: 8
      httpGet:
        host: 127.0.0.1
        path: /healthz
        port: 10259
        scheme: HTTPS
      initialDelaySeconds: 15
      timeoutSeconds: 15
    name: kube-scheduler
    resources:
      requests:
        cpu: 100m
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /etc/kubernetes/scheduler.conf
      name: kubeconfig
      readOnly: true
  hostNetwork: true
  priorityClassName: system-cluster-critical
  volumes:
  - hostPath:
      path: /etc/kubernetes/scheduler.conf
      type: FileOrCreate
    name: kubeconfig
status: {}
```

**kube-controller-manager.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    component: kube-controller-manager
    tier: control-plane
  name: kube-controller-manager
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  containers:
  - command:
    - kube-controller-manager
    - --allocate-node-cidrs=true
    - --authentication-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/controller-manager.conf
    - --authorization-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/controller-manager.conf
    - --bind-address=127.0.0.1
    - --client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt
    - --cluster-cidr=10.244.0.0/16
    - --cluster-name=kubernetes
    - --cluster-signing-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt
    - --cluster-signing-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.key
    - --controllers=*,bootstrapsigner,tokencleaner
    - --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/controller-manager.conf
    - --leader-elect=true
    - --node-cidr-mask-size=24
    - --port=0
    - --requestheader-client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy-ca.crt
    - --root-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt
    - --service-account-private-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/sa.key
    - --service-cluster-ip-range=10.96.0.0/12
    - --use-service-account-credentials=true
    image: k8s.gcr.io/kube-controller-manager:v1.18.6
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    livenessProbe:
      failureThreshold: 8
      httpGet:
        host: 127.0.0.1
        path: /healthz
        port: 10257
        scheme: HTTPS
      initialDelaySeconds: 15
      timeoutSeconds: 15
    name: kube-controller-manager
    resources:
      requests:
        cpu: 200m
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /etc/ssl/certs
      name: ca-certs
      readOnly: true
    - mountPath: /etc/pki
      name: etc-pki
      readOnly: true
    - mountPath: /usr/libexec/kubernetes/kubelet-plugins/volume/exec
      name: flexvolume-dir
    - mountPath: /etc/kubernetes/pki
      name: k8s-certs
      readOnly: true
    - mountPath: /etc/kubernetes/controller-manager.conf
      name: kubeconfig
      readOnly: true
  hostNetwork: true
  priorityClassName: system-cluster-critical
  volumes:
  - hostPath:
      path: /etc/ssl/certs
      type: DirectoryOrCreate
    name: ca-certs
  - hostPath:
      path: /etc/pki
      type: DirectoryOrCreate
    name: etc-pki
  - hostPath:
      path: /usr/libexec/kubernetes/kubelet-plugins/volume/exec
      type: DirectoryOrCreate
    name: flexvolume-dir
  - hostPath:
      path: /etc/kubernetes/pki
      type: DirectoryOrCreate
    name: k8s-certs
  - hostPath:
      path: /etc/kubernetes/controller-manager.conf
      type: FileOrCreate
    name: kubeconfig
status: {}
```

So these are using ports 10259 and 10257 respectively.
Any idea why is kubectl trying to perform health check using 10251 and 10252?

version:

```
kubectl version 
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"18", GitVersion:"v1.18.6", GitCommit:"dff82dc0de47299ab66c83c626e08b245ab19037", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-07-15T16:58:53Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.9", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"} 
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"18", GitVersion:"v1.18.6", GitCommit:"dff82dc0de47299ab66c83c626e08b245ab19037", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-07-15T16:51:04Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.9", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

PS: I am able to make deployments and expose services, no problem there.

Comment: You should mention your exact kubernetes version. I know the issue with Component Status was always there in a way. For me even though cluster was working it was always showing "unhealthy" or "unknown" status.

Comment: [root@master01 manifests]# kubectl version


Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"18", GitVersion:"v1.18.6", GitCommit:"dff82dc0de47299ab66c83c626e08b245ab19037", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-07-15T16:58:53Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.9", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}


Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"18", GitVersion:"v1.18.6", GitCommit:"dff82dc0de47299ab66c83c626e08b245ab19037", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-07-15T16:51:04Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.9", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

Comment: @MarceloPrego please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63136175/edit) to include specifics like that, and reserve the use of comments for commentary

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a known issue which unfortunately is not going to be fixed as the feature is [planned to be deprecated](https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/issues/553#issuecomment-529591505). Also, see this [source](https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/173#issuecomment-664430043):

> I wouldn't expect a change for this issue. Upstream Kubernetes wants
> to deprecate component status and does not plan on enhancing it. If
> you need to check for cluster health using other monitoring sources is
> recommended.
>
> [kubernetes/kubernetes#93171](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/93171) - 'fix component status server address'
> which is getting recommendation to close due to deprecation talk.
>
> [kubernetes/enhancements#553](https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/issues/553) - Deprecate ComponentStatus
>
> [kubernetes/kubeadm#2222](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/2222) - kubeadm default init and they are looking to
> 'start printing a warning in kubect get componentstatus that this API
> object is no longer supported and there are plans to remove it.'